# Concatenate BLOB to a string

Tags: php, blob, concatenation

I am trying to figure out if I can conatanate a BLOB containing picture information to a string, containing text data?  I am thinking no, but I am hoping yes!

Let me try and clear up my question a little bit.  I am attempting to pull user information in addition to a photograph of that user out of my tables and present them to the user.  I was hoping all of that information could be tossed back out to the user as an echo statement and I could then use jquery to pick it up asynchronously.  I was hoping I would have to make two ajax calls.  I may have to it seems.

Comment: Do you need to send the image data via ajax, or could you send a URL instead and let the browser send a separate request to handle the image data?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your alternative solution?

Comment: For example, if you created a [dedicated page for displaying images from the database](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Display_an_image_stored_in_a_database__PHP_-16637.html), you could send the URL to display that image instead of the raw image data.  The front-end would then take that URL and drop it into an [`Image` object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp), and the browser would send a separate HTTP request to retrieve the image.  This way, you only send string data for the ajax request, and you only send image data for the image request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that MySQL text data is zero terminated.
So the first `\0` in the blob will break the string.

You will need to use `quote` to escape the blob data.

Not 100% sure this will work.

```
SELECT CONCAT(stringfield
            , QUOTE(CAST(a.ar_options AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8)) 
       as bitmapstring
FROM ...
```